# printing Integer using BufferedOutputStream in java

Tags: java

Need to print a million values in console, `System.out.println()` is comparatively slow when compared to `BufferedOutputStream`(*from what I read*).

So I tried to print this way:

```
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream (System.out);
out.write(sum);
```

Since `sum` is of the type `int`, and the `out.write()` is printing in bytes. I tried to convert bytes to decimal, which gave me a compilation error saying:

> byte cannot be dereferenced

So, my **problem** is: to print integer values in decimal format using `BufferedOutputStream`.

Since, I did not find any solution here in printing `int` values using `BufferedOutputStream`, I am desperately looking for an answer.

Comment: Console? Is this for debugging purpose?

Comment: No, its for a problem in hackerrank, I normally prints using System.out.println() . and which easily gets verified by their compiler. So, as of now, All I need is to print things super quick, :)

Comment: Create a StringBuilder, append your ints to it, call System.out.println() once with that StringBuilder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that *displaying text* on the console is much slower than generating it.  You can use a buffer and if redirected to a file, instead of the screen this will be faster, however if you are actually displaying on the screen it won't be much faster.  What buffering can do is reduce the amount of scrolling since it writes to the screen in lumps of text instead of one line at a time.

Note: BufferedOutputStream writes *binary* not text. It will be faster but is not human readable. If you want human readable I suggest using PrintWriter which is designed to write text.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                  new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8")));

// call many times
out.print(num);

// to flush the buffer so all the data can be read.
out.flush();
```

You could use a StringBuilder, however this is;

- slower as you are not displaying text until the whole string has been created. As noted, the displaying of the text is your main problem.
- uses as much memory as the output, and doesn't scale well.

Comment: I am using this on an online compiler(hackerrank) , right now I get a slight time out , hope using this would reduce that :)

Comment: @shaheen in that case the output is going to a file so it is unlikely to make much difference. I suggest you profile you code to see where it is spending most of it's time. Also you want to minimise the time complexity of your code, i.e. any loops inside loops.

Comment: btw, I get an error in compiler, printwriter cannot be converted to outputStream :/

Comment: @shaheen OutputStream is for binary, not text. Are you expected to produce text or binary?

Comment: the complexity is O (nlogn) now. And on the discussion I read not using printf made a big difference!

Comment: `int sum = 300` . need to print `300` thats all :)

Comment: @shaheen so you want to print just one number? and you think this is where the most time is being spent?  Buffering will only help when you have a very large number of numbers to print e.g. thousands or millions.  I suspect you are spending most of your time before you  print the number.

Comment: No, I just used `300` as an analogy, million numbers indeed, I used 300 in case you got confused with my unclear question,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106212/discussion-between-shaheen-and-peter-lawrey).

Comment: If you have millions of values, buffering will help. If you need to write text you need a Writer, not an OutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help...

```
byte[] ascii = Integer.toString(sum).getBytes();

OutputStream console = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out);

try {

  console.write(ascii);

  console.flush();

} catch (IOException e) {

  e.printStackTrace();

}
```

But you'll have to check if this code is faster than

```
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score -2):

use BigInteger(bytes), it will get you the integer in a BigInteger format.

Comment: How will this help print an `int` value faster?